# Facebook login button doesn't appear on all browsers

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I created an HTML page with Facebook login button which users can login. The button some times doesn't appear in chrome & other browsers. I checked and the same version of chrome it will appear on one computer but not the other. When using incognito the button will appear. I need a coding solution as I can't send my users to login using incognito... Thanks!

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '------',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      status: true,
      version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  };

load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Is it possible the button doesn't appear if you're already logged in? Just like when you visit facebook.com, they send you right to your feed? Incognito ignores existing cookies, which makes the button always appear.

Comment: Thanks Chris, no its  not the issue. I tried logging out and clearing cache. still the same issue. I debugged the code and I see window.fbAsyncInit = function()  is not called.

Comment: Most likely due to some privacy filter extension, that prevents the SDK from loading in the first place …?